# Why does jssStyles need to be removed in componentDidUpdate or useEffect when using material-ui with NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have read the material-ui docs on SSR and looked at their example app [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript), and configured my _document.js and _app.tsx to be the same.

However, for whatever reason my app's styling breaks when I add the componentDidUpdate to remove the jss styles like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector("#jss-server-side");

    if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
}
```

So, I want to find out why is this step needed in the first place, and what side-effects would I face if I were to remove it?

Also, I still get the `Warning: Prop className did not match` even with all this.. Is there another way to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "my app's styling breaks"? Are no styles applied at all or different styles than you expected?
It would also be helpful if you provide a minimal reproducible example since you mixed code from the example with your own code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yeah, for some reason some of pages lose all styling.. as in the styles I create with mui's makeStyles function don't get applied..

Answer (score 0):

jssStyles are used to prevent the FOUC where a web page appears briefly with the browser's default styles prior to loading an external stylesheet and since Next.js is rendered in the server side jssStyles is not required and hence you remove it.

Refer:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content
[Server Rendering with Material-UI - removing `jss-server-side` afterwards.. bad workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697287/server-rendering-with-material-ui-removing-jss-server-side-afterwards-bad)