# Server Rendering with Material-UI - removing `jss-server-side` afterwards.. bad workflow?

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I do use material-ui with nextjs.
In the documentation of material-ui I found this [#the-client-side](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#the-client-side) about implementing material-ui:

```js
function Main() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I wonder if this is a good workflow, as all the generated styles are shipped to the client and only will be decoupled from the DOM there.

Wouldn't it be much better to remove them within the build-process - or use another way - so that the styles won't be send to the client at least?

**BTW:**
I've copied the generated Styles to a seperate file to check the filesize. The unnecessary transfered styles are > 30kb !!

Comment: I've figured out. this Styles are used to prevent the FOUC. Is there any way to optimize this Stylesheets, so that only those ones are loaded, which are really used in the current Page? ... AND could they be compressed (uglified)?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: This is explained like this in the docs https://v4.mui.com/guides/server-rendering/#the-client-side This approach is the correct workflow @suther